# What is the best way to create a canvas drawing that fits the activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a canvas drawing in android but inside the emulator it looks centered. When deploy in a cell phone or tablet, the drawing is at a corner. I read that you need to override onMeasure but not sure how that will work when you draw the bitmap / or set layout parameters.

Comment: What does your layout XML look like?  How are you positioning it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always have a View as Fill_Parent and draw on the view's canvas.

Comment: I added height to be wrap_content and width to fill_parent. The bitmap use in the canvas instead of using the root layout height was set to half the size.